# Sort algorithm c++

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Test()
    {
 
    }
    Test(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }
    bool operator<(Test&);
 
};
bool Test::operator<(Test& rValue) {
    return this->value < rValue.value;
}
int main()
{
    Test* arr = new Test[950];
    arr[0] = Test(5);
    arr[1] = Test(10);
    arr[2] = Test(7);
    arr[3] = Test(3);
    arr[4] = Test(10);
    sort(arr, arr + 5, [](Test& a, Test& b) { return a < b ? false : true; });
}
```

Sort algorithm works perfectly until there are objects with same grade value.

P.S I know other way to use sort and reverse.

I'm using visual studio 2019

ERROR:
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: invalid comparator

Comment: Could you please add full text of the error?

Comment: Aside, a default `Test` object will have an unitialized `value` field.

Comment: Do you want to order in descending order?

Comment: The problem is that the comparator function yoyr passing to sort, return true for equal elemtents

Comment: You cannot negate `operator<` and use it for sorting, as `!(a < b)` is equal to `a >= b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sort comparator must return `false` for items that are equal, yours returns `true`.

Try this instead.

```
sort(arr, arr + 5, [](Test& a, Test& b) { return b < a; });
```

Comment: @BerianidzeLuka Debug assertions are not executed in Release mode.

Comment: You said that sort comparator must return false for equal items,but how this problem is fixed in release? operator stays < like it is

Comment: If you do not return false for equal items then your program has undefined behaviour. Working is one possible outcome of undefined behaviour, but obviously you cannot rely on that. The program is still incorrect even if the bug does not show itself.